# Book about alien birds

Tags: story-identification

The book is about alien birds that must dock and flap their wings to keep islands afloat on their home planet. All of a sudden aliens attack them and slaughter most of them. The birds have at least one space ship, and a few escape on that.

The birds find a water planet, and decide to explore it. They notice a large object under water; when they try to check it out, they crash. Only one bird survives the crash; he finds some sort of tentacle monster (?), and survives off it.

The bird eventually leaves the water planet, becomes part of a space ship, and battles other aliens. Both sides have powerful ships which end up destroying galaxies.

The birds in the beginning also play a VR game about being god. They try to help one race become more powerful. A more detailed bit of the game is they main protagonist, the bird, has these animals that cannot lookup so he clears the sky so that they can look up which leads to the enemy destroying them because the enemy can finally see a race to kill (all in the simulation VR game). The game is something the birds have on their homeworld; I think it's implanted in their heads. It's an activity for them to do while they're docked, keeping the islands afloat.

As far as I can recall, the birds were presented as looking much like actual birds here on Earth, with wings and talons (no hands, for example).

I read the book in 2017; I'm not sure how old it was then, and I don't remember anything about the cover.

Extra detail: There might have been crystals on the islands crystals that helped keep them floating.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour, to be clear on how the site works. You've provided a fair bit of information, but some isn't completely clear. If you can remember any more detail, it would help. You may want to look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/80867) for ideas on additonal information you could provide. Common things include: When did you read the book? Do you have any clue as to how old the book was at that point? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: Thank you I will check it out! I remember reading the book about a year ago. I am not sure how old the book is and I do not remember anything about the cover.

Comment: From what's in the question already: Was the "rescue" spaceship something the birds had available, or was it provided by an alien race? When the surviving bird battles other aliens, is it on a space ship itself (I assume so, but it's not completely clear)? If so, where did *this* space ship come from? With respect to the VR game, is that something the birds have on their home planet, or something provided on the "rescue" ship? can you provide any clarification on the nature of the birds - do they manipulate things with talons, or do they have hands of some sort?

Comment: You can [edit] additional information directly into the question - it gets noticed better than simply adding it in with the comments.

Comment: From what I remember the birds already had the rescue ship. The escaping birds travel across space to find a new home planet and find a water planet. They find a large object under water so they go to check it out and crash. They end up dying except the main character, a bird, who survives off a tentacle monster (?) that keeps him alive for a long time. After escaping he becomes part of a space ship and battles other aliens outside of the VR game. The VR game is something for the birds to do while docked. They have talons I believe.

Comment: Alright thanks for the tip, I’m on mobile so it’s harder for me.

Comment: Understood entirely. I hope you don't mind, I took the liberty of trying to merge the additional detail you added into appropriate parts of the narrative, to make it easier to track. If you don't like my edit, feel free to edit it yourself; if you really hate it, you can [roll it back](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/195970/revisions). Good luck on finding your story!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[The Ellimist Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ellimist_Chronicles)* by K.A Applegate a companion book to the *Animorph* series that explain the backstory of one of the characters

> As an unnamed Animorph lies on the brink of death, the Ellimist appears and recounts his origins as Azure Level, Seven Spar, Extension Two, Down-Messenger, Forty-One (Toomin) the Ketran and his transfiguration into the Ellimist as a final request to the dying Animorph. The Ketran race was virtually extinguished by the Capasins, who had seen transmissions of violent virtual Ketran games that had been broadcast into space and mistook them for a violent species that meddled with other ones. A Ketran named Toomin was one of the few survivors. These survivors became space nomads, seeking a replacement for their home planet. Toomin became the leader of this group and was the only survivor when it crash-landed on a mostly aquatic moon. His mind was absorbed and kept alive at the bottom of the sea by a moon-spanning entity known as Father that absorbed the information in the brain (or equivalent) of every corpse on it. After defeating Father at music, Toomin began to grow too intelligent for Father and defeated him, incorporating all the memories of corpses on the moon, eventually becoming a blending of minds.

Comment: Thank you! This is one that of my favorite books.